# What is the best way to say 'value for money'?

Tags: traducción

What is the best and most frequently used way to say 'value for money' in Spanish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Spanish you would say that something

> Tiene una buena (o mala) **relación calidad-precio**

Answer (score 2):

> 'El mejor valor por su dinero'. ('the best value for your money')

It's so commonly used by Mexicans that is often abused by advertisers, marketers, and retailers all over Mexico to the point that it sounds cliched

Comment: Why the downvote?